# Capturing API Management request through diagnosis settings and event hub in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics

I am using a goat function app [AzureGoat](https://github.com/ine-labs/AzureGoat). I have integrated my AzureGoat function app into API Management Azure. When I test a GET request from the API management console then I am getting logs in event hub but when I browse the AzureGoat URL through browser, I am not getting anything. So, I want to get the logs when I access the URL through brower. Any help would be highly appreciated. If you need more information please let me know.

In API management I can test my AzureGoat function app API and I am getting 200 Response when I am sending any request. Now instead of sending the manual request from the console of API management, I want to get the logs in event hub when I access the URL through brower.

Comment: When you're testing in browser are you making a call to function directly or to API Management?

Comment: we are currently try to figure that out actually, Could you please let us know how can we do it?

Comment: Do you test using Test tab in APIMs APIs view?

Comment: Yes, We have tested using Test tab.

Comment: I was looking online and found about log-to-eventhub policy, Is that gonna help at all if I add it in the inbound policy?

Comment: How do you configure EventHub integration?

Comment: I actually saw that we didnt do the eventhub integration, so we need to create a logger right? and then log to eventhub policy. Will that work?

Comment: As far as APIM - EventHub integration is concerned, there are two places where it could be configured. One is Diagnostic Settings, where you can specify target EventHub to receive APIM request telemetry. The other is indeed through creating a logger and using log-to-eventhub policy, this one allows you to emit any messages from request processing pipeline.

Comment: I have started gettting logs when i access the function url, however these logs are like too much, any possibility i could shorten them? Like for gateway url logs I used log to event hub policy